# optimising select_related fields for auth user profile

Tags: django

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
      user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
      dob = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
      otherfields = ......

class Comment(models.Model):
      author = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I want to include DOB only in select.

```
q = Comment.objects.all().select_related('author__profile__dob')
```

But if i do q.query it showing `otherfields` too in select statement how to get rid of it ? i also used `.only('author__profile__dob')` but this did't solve the problem

Comment: This sounds like an unnecessary micro optimisation. What does it matter if that field is included?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to join a column not a table

```
# Joins author and pofile
q = Comment.objects.all().select_related('author__profile')

# Selects only dob field
q = q.only('author__profile__dob')
```

But be aware: if you use [only](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.only) you must list all required fields in query. Probably you want [defer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#defer).

Comment: As I said, only makes you list all fields you want.
Try this: only('id') and take a look at the query. It should create joins and select ids only.